# Place matrix and graph side-by-side

Tags: sidebyside

I am trying to place a matrix and a graph side-by-side in a tabular format, using the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{p{5cm}c}\vspace{-3cm}
    {$\displaystyle
    \textbf{A}=
    \begin{pmatrix}
        10 & 2 & 1 & 4 & 0\\
        2 & 10 & 0 & 0 & 2\\
        1 & 0 & 10 & 0 & 0\\
        4 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 1\\
        0 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 10
    \end{pmatrix}
    $}
    &
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        [auto=left,every node/.style={circle, draw=black, thick, minimum size=0.5cm}]
        \node (0) at (0,1.5) {0};
        \node (1) at (1.5,3) {1};
        \node (2) at (1.5,1.5) {2};
        \node (3) at (1.5,0) {3};
        \node (4) at (3,1.5) {4};
        \draw[-] (0) to (1);
        \draw[-] (0) to (2);
        \draw[-] (0) to (3);
        \draw[-] (1) to (4);
        \draw[-] (3) to (4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
\label{ex}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

This is correct, but I would like to put the symbol $\implies$ between the matrix and the graph. How can I do that?
It is my first question here, so I am sorry for layout error.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be better to surround the example with code for being compilable with LaTeX, but it's not a big deal here.

Comment: One solution is to change the column specification to `p{5cm}@{$\implies$}c` which would result in the symbol between the two columns. I did not test vertical alignment though.

Comment: Don't use `\begin{center}` in a `figure` environment. This adds unwanted space. Instead use `\centering`.

Comment: Also, in a math environment I'd use `\mathbf` not `\textbf`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I use p{5cm}@{$\implies$}c, I get this error: Missing p-arg in array arg. \begin{tabular}p

Comment: You forgot the braces around the whole thing. But the alignment isn't good, so don't bother.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for the `tabular`, place the `tikzpicure` inside the math. You just need `baseline=(2.base)` in the optional argument of the `tikzpicture` to get the proper vertical alignment.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}    

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
$\displaystyle
    \mathbf{A}=
    \begin{pmatrix}
        10 & 2 & 1 & 4 & 0\\
        2 & 10 & 0 & 0 & 2\\
        1 & 0 & 10 & 0 & 0\\
        4 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 1\\
        0 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 10
    \end{pmatrix}
\implies
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(2.base),auto=left,every node/.style={circle, draw=black, thick, minimum size=0.5cm}]
        \node (0) at (0,1.5) {0};
        \node (1) at (1.5,3) {1};
        \node (2) at (1.5,1.5) {2};
        \node (3) at (1.5,0) {3};
        \node (4) at (3,1.5) {4};
        \draw[-] (0) to (1);
        \draw[-] (0) to (2);
        \draw[-] (0) to (3);
        \draw[-] (1) to (4);
        \draw[-] (3) to (4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
$
\caption{Caption}
\label{ex}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```